# Jenkins lost the jobs after bulk upgrading the plugins

Tags: jenkins

I new this could be an old post, but wanted to understand and fix my issue:

I have a maven job in jenkins which works fine when I build it.

I saw an alert for existing plugins i.e update available, so I selected all plugins and did update; all of a sudden I lost my old projects/jobs in jenkins but the jenkins folder structure is still having the jobs.

Tried:

1. copy pasting the job folder from my backup-- didn't fix the issue.
2. installing a new jenkins.war file had showed the project/job in folder structure but not in dashboard
3. had tried to create new maven project but not getting maven option after clicking on jenkins>>New item>> no maven project here..

Any suggestions please.

Comment: did you check jenkins log?

Comment: ul 12, 2016 4:10:42 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed
SEVERE: Failed Loading job ApplicationHealth_Maven
java.io.IOException: Unable to read C:\Users\kancharp\.jenkins\jobs\ApplicationHealth_Maven\config.xml
 at hudson.XmlFile.read(XmlFile.java:144)
 at hudson.model.Items.load(Items.java:326)
 at jenkins.model.Jenkins$17.run(Jenkins.java:2685)
 at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
 at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)

Comment: yeah in jenkins.err log it showed above error.. no change done to job/config.xml file

Comment: Your jenkins version and plugins may not be up to date.

Comment: yes, my plugins are not updated, when i tried to update plugin then i found this issue. i.e lost the project/job from jenkins dashboard view.

could you suggest, which version (.war) is stable to install and jenkins windows service version aswell.

Comment: after installing the jenkins 1.630 version i got the dashboard, but had to recreate the job and configuration..

thanks everyone for your comments